# How tell PHPStorm debugger, that my project has document root other than project root

Tags: php, debugging, xdebug, phpstorm

I'am trying to set up PHPStorm with xdebug. Everyting launches fine, but breakpoints just do not work and have  "x" symbol on them.

[image]

I'm using [openserver](http://open-server.ru/) with PHP 5.4 and editing files directly on the local web server, so no file mapping is necessary.

I think, that my problem is that web server root is located below the project root directory (for security reasons) and PHPStorm does not that.

Project root: **C:\OpenServer\domains\mysite**

Web server root (configured in nginx): **C:\OpenServer\domains\mysite\httpdocs**

How do I tell PHPStorm, that the index.php that webserver runs is actually **C:\OpenServer\domains\mysite\httpdocs\index.php**, but not **C:\OpenServer\domains\mysite\index.php**?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you running Xdebug via HTTP or via CLI? Have you configured the webserver root also within you Phpstorm project? And first of all: What does breakpoints do not work mean? The code does not halt at that point? Have you tried with a point where halting is more obvious? Try that first before digging deeper in. It might be that the debugging sessions just didn't start.

Comment: Did you resolve this? I am having a similar issue with a project also with a sub directory. My breakpoints hit on index.php but not in other files. (Though they all have the tick symbol displayed).

Comment: I'm also having a similar problem.  Breaking on first line functions normally, but setting a breakpoint does absolutely nothing.  I can step into all code files, but cannot use breakpoints.

After exhausting all other alleys, I've come to the conclusion PHPStorm is choking on the root path (which in my case is in "src" inside the project root).  The XDebug logs clearly indicate the correct file path for my path mapping, but the breakpoints do not function.

Comment: The X in the breakpoint button is only there to suggest that if you click on it, the breakpoint will be deleted, not that the breakpoint is broken.

Answer (score 6):

You have to use path mapping. 
You can find it in debug server configuration
[image: Debug server configuration window]

Check out official docs and vids:

- [Help page](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/debugging-php-applications.html)
- [PHP Debugging webinar recording](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LUTolQw8K9A)
- [JIT debugging](http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/12/just-in-time-debugging-and-php-exception-breakpoints-with-phpstorm-and-xdebug/)
- [Smart step into](http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/07/debugging-with-smart-step-into/)
- [Simultaneous debug sessions](http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/04/simultaneous-debugging-sessions-in-phpstorm/)

Comment: Definitely the right answer. Someone give this poor guy some points!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I tried these steps:

- step 1: uncheck these two options at xdebug section
  [image]

  - step 2: copy & paste the directory of your project at `/xampp/htdocs/{your-project}`
    [image]