# PhpStorm mutualized deployment conflicting server root URL

Tags: phpstorm, setting, phpstorm-2018.1

How to set an absolute project URL, different from the root server URL ?

I look for solutions other than:

1. [Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289205/how-tell-phpstorm-debugger-that-my-project-has-document-root-other-than-project): seems out of date (I run PS-181)
2. [leaving server root url empty, tip from Jason Lotito](https://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/WI-3414).

   - The second works for me but the GUI keeps yelling that the server root URL is not specified.
   - But no longer works if the

Did anyone came with a proper, better solution?

EDIT: How to set the project URL

1. File
2. Settings
3. Build, Execution, Deployment
4. Deployment

   - tab Connection: set "web server root URL"
   - tab Mappings: set "web path on server"

[image: screenshot of the problem]

EDIT 2:

> So you are sharing the same deployment entry between multiple projects... Why not just make it visible to current project only ... so it become project specific and you enter any data you want without any hacks (as it will have no influence on another project). P.S. The ticket you have mentioned was created long time ago when there were shared entries only. project-specific entries are available for quite few years now... –

I precisely use the same deployment between multiple projects: I have multiple mutualized servers. The only difference between projects of the same server belongs to the "mappings" tab.
Moreover, if I set the `Web server root URL` to my project domain, I have to hack again the `Web path on server ...` but putting something (like a /), which is a crappy solution.

Clicking `Visible only for this project` means that I have to create new deployment for each project (which becomes tedious after 30 copy/paste).

As said in the old ticket, if the `Project URL` of the `mappings tab` were an editable text field, all would be much simpler.

Comment: Details please. What URL you need to provide and what do you have right now?

Comment: Thanks for having a look ; I edited the post with screenshot and how to get to that setting.

Comment: Thanks for updates ... but unfortunately I still do not understand your problem ... and the 2 links you gave are about different things (from what I see).

Comment: As I understand you have a SFTP deployment entry that uses `http://my.site.com` as Web Server root URL... and you **share** that deployment entry **between more than one project** .. and in 2nd/other project you want to have `http:///my.example.com` as web URL. Am I correct?

Comment: Not exactly: I have no root URL, the projects are only accessed via domain names. I a way, we could say that my server root URL is `http://server.ip.adress` while my projects web paths are `https://my.domain.com`, `http://another.domain.org`, etc.

Comment: So you are **sharing** the same deployment entry between multiple projects... Why not just make it **visible to current project only** ... so it become project specific and you enter any data you want without any hacks (as it will have no influence on another project). **P.S.** The ticket you have mentioned was created long time ago when there were shared entries only. project-specific entries are available for quite few years now...

Comment: New edit (because comment formatting is too restricting)

Comment: Well ... in such case -- no other way. If you need shared entries then what that ticket says (and what you are doing already) must be the only way. P.S. I'm on another hand do not see a big deal in making per project entries -- it's not like you are creating new entry every day... But then -- I have no idea what projects you are working on...

Comment: That's topsy... cret ;-) Thanks for your expertise!